# get local IPv4 of computer using VB.net

Tags: vb.net, ipv4

I'm trying to get the ip address of my local PC, and one one of my other PCs it gets the v4 address fine, but on this one the code:

```
Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName).AddressList(0).ToString()
```

returns what I guess is a IPv6 address:

```
fe80::9c09:e2e:4736:4c62%11
```

How do I get the IPv4 address?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Disclaimer**- I don't have IPv6 installed and there is probably a much better way to do this, but what does the following return:

```
Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList
    .Where(a => !a.IsIPv6LinkLocal && !a.IsIPv6Multicast && !a.IsIPv6SiteLocal)
    .First()
    .ToString();
```

Edit - didn't notice you were asking in VB, so I've tried translating it to:

```
Dim s As String = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList _
    .Where(Function(a As IPAddress) Not a.IsIPv6LinkLocal AndAlso Not a.IsIPv6Multicast AndAlso Not a.IsIPv6SiteLocal) _
    .First() _
    .ToString()
```

This may blow up, so don't treat it as production code.

Comment: Jonathan- I didn't see the VB tags, so posted my answer in C#. I've now (hopefully) translated it into VB.NET.

Comment: @RichardOD How stable is this code? By the way thanks for pointing that out Sir.

Comment: It is VB, using Linq

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution for getting a routable IPv4 IP without using an external service:

```
  Function GetLocalIP() As String
    Dim IPList As System.Net.IPHostEntry = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(System.Net.Dns.GetHostName)

    For Each IPaddress In IPList.AddressList
      'Only return IPv4 routable IPs
      If (IPaddress.AddressFamily = Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork) AndAlso (Not IsPrivateIP(IPaddress.ToString)) Then
        Return IPaddress.ToString
      End If
    Next
    Return ""
  End Function

  Function IsPrivateIP(ByVal CheckIP As String) As Boolean
    Dim Quad1, Quad2 As Integer

    Quad1 = CInt(CheckIP.Substring(0, CheckIP.IndexOf(".")))
    Quad2 = CInt(CheckIP.Substring(CheckIP.IndexOf(".") + 1).Substring(0, CheckIP.IndexOf(".")))
    Select Case Quad1
      Case 10
        Return True
      Case 172
        If Quad2 >= 16 And Quad2 <= 31 Then Return True
      Case 192
        If Quad2 = 168 Then Return True
    End Select
    Return False
  End Function
```

Note that my code is also verifying that the range is routable (IsPrivateIP).  You can remove or modify that part if you are looking for something else.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use this:

```
 Dim tmpHostName As String = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()
 myIPaddress = System.Net.Dns.GetHostByName(tmpHostName).AddressList(0).ToString()
```

`GetHostByName` is obsolete but this is the way to get the IPv4.  Why? Because the `getbyhostname` function is created before IPv6 so the function get only the IPv4 connection, not the `fe80::9c09:e2e:4736:4c62%11`.

Answer (score 0):

Something maybe fun is this little function that'll show all IP addresses on your computer:

```
Public Function getOwnIp() As String
        Dim hostIP As IPHostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName())
        Dim position As Integer = 0
        Dim ip As String = Nothing
        While ipList < hostIP.AddressList.Length
            ip += hostIP.AddressList(position).ToString & vbCrLf
            position += 1
        End While`enter code here`
        Return ip
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the answer to this question myself and I could not find one suitable to my needs. I managed to experiment with various answers across the net until I came up with this (works great!). Just thought I would share since this post is the top result via Google.

```
    ''''Routine to fetch IPv4 Network addresses for all local network interfaces.
    Dim adapters As NetworkInterface() = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
    Dim adapter As NetworkInterface
        For Each adapter In adapters
            Dim properties As IPInterfaceProperties = adapter.GetIPProperties()
            If properties.UnicastAddresses.Count > 0 Then
                For Each unicastadress As UnicastIPAddressInformation In properties.UnicastAddresses
                    Dim ip As IPAddress = unicastadress.Address
                    If ip.AddressFamily = AddressFamily.InterNetwork Then
                        ComboBox1.Items.Add(ip.ToString)
                    End If
                Next unicastadress
            End If
        Next adapter
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to import the system namespace into your application and then create an instance of the ***`System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPAddressInformation`*** and use it as such

Example

```
  Imports system.data.sqlclient
    imports system

Public class Form1
   Dim IPAdd As System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPAddressInformation

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

 MsgBox("My IP Address is " & IPAdd.Address.ToString)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Dim localIp As IPHostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName())
 txtLocal.Text = localIp.AddressList(1).ToString
```

Notice that I changed the `(0)` index to `(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

I used a combined Cmd/Visual Basic code and it worked :

```
    Dim ResString As String = "result.txt"

    If File.Exists("result.txt") Then
        File.Delete("result.txt")
    End If

    Shell("cmd.exe /c  cd " & Application.StartupPath & " && ipconfig >> " & ResString & "&& exit", AppWinStyle.NormalFocus)

    Dim Ipv4 As String
    Dim Ipv4Found As Boolean = False
    Dim Ipv4Char As Integer = 43
    Dim Ipv4Str As String
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500)
    'Wait some seconds to create "result.txt"

    Dim Ipv4Reader As StreamReader
    Ipv4Reader = File.OpenText("result.txt")

    Do Until Ipv4Found = True

        Ipv4Str = Ipv4Reader.ReadLine()
        If Not Ipv4Str = Nothing Then
            If Ipv4Str.Contains("IPv4") Then
                Try
                    Ipv4 = Ipv4Str.Chars(Ipv4Char)
                    Do Until Ipv4Char = 60
                        Ipv4Char = Ipv4Char + 1
                        Ipv4 = Ipv4 & Ipv4Str.Chars(Ipv4Char)
                        'Read results step by step
                    Loop
                Catch ex As Exception
                End Try
                MsgBox("Your IPv4 Address is " & Ipv4)
                Ipv4Found = True
                Ipv4Reader.Close()

            End If
        Else

        End If
    Loop
```

If your computer language is english you may have some unusual characters in the IPv4 String ( My pc is actually in Italian )

Answer (score 0):

This one works on my side

```
Dim IPaddressList = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList
        Dim IPaddrPC As String = ""
        For Each item In IPaddressList
            If item.AddressFamily = Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork Then
                IPaddrPC = item.Address.ToString
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
```